# Reference of hadith in Musnad Ahmed which states the wearing taweez/amulet is shirk?

Tags: hadith, source-identification, shirk, tawiz

What is the complete reference including volume and hadith number for hadith that states *wearing amulet is shirk* in **Musnad Ahmed**?

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amulet): "An amulet is an object whose most important characteristic is the power ascribed to it to protect its owner from danger or harm."

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I assume the hadith is what you are looking for:

1. > It was narrated that Uqbah ibn Aamir said: I heard the Messenger of
   >   Allah (pbuh) say: “Whoever wears an amulet, may Allah not fulfil his
   >   need, and whoever wears a sea-shell, may Allah not give him peace.”
   >   (Masnud Ahmed  16951.) *classed as da’eef(weak) by Shaykh al-Albaani in Da’eef al-Jaami’, 5703*
2. > It was narrated from Uqbah ibn Aamir al-Juhani that a group came to
   >   the Messenger of Allah (pbuh) [to swear their allegiance (bay’ah) to
   >   him]. He accepted the bay’ah of nine of them but not of one of them.
   >   They said, “O Messenger of Allah, you accepted the bay’ah of nine but
   >   not of this one.” He said, “He is wearing an amulet.” The man put his
   >   hand (in his shirt) and took it off, then he (the Prophet (pbuh))
   >   accepted his bay’ah. He said, ‘**Whoever wears an amulet has committed
   >   shirk**.” [Masnud Ahmed 16969] *classed as saheeh(Correct) by Shaykh al-Albaani in al-Silsilah al-Saheehah, 492*

Answer (score 2):

السلام عليكم ورحمة الله وبركاته

Brother, the complete hadith you are referring to is:

> > *It was narrated from ‘Uqbah ibn ‘Aamir al-Juhani that a group came to the Messenger of Allaah (ﷺ) [to swear their allegiance (bay’ah) to him]. He accepted the bay’ah of nine of them but not of one of them. They said, “O Messenger of Allaah, you accepted the bay’ah of nine but not of this one.” He said, “He is wearing an amulet.” The man put his hand (in his shirt) and took it off, then he (ﷺ) accepted his bay’ah. He ﷺ said, **‘Whoever wears an amulet has committed shirk.”***

References;

1. *Musnad Ahmad (Volume: 28 / Pg. 637, Risalah Edition) Hadith No. 17423*
2. *Mustardak al-Hakim, Hadith Number: 7513*

••••••

It has been classified as ***Sahīh*** by al-Albānī in:

1. *Ṣaḥīḥ Targeeb Wat Tarheeb, No. 3455*
2. *Silsillah As-Saheeha, No. 492*
3. *Ṣaḥīḥ al-Jāmī', Hadeeth Number: 6394*
4. *Ghayatul Maram Takhreej (No. 294)*

Answer (score 0):

I searched for this hadith and found that the number is 17558. I read this hadith in Urdu version. Please correct me if i am wrong.

Answer (score -2):

http://ahlesunnatpak.com/al-musnad-by-imam-e-ahmad-%D8%B1%D8%AD%D9%85%DB%81-%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%84%DB%81/

Download Volume 7.

The number is 17558.

Comment: It is best if you quote the hadith from your reference and provide an English translation (as this is an English-only site). See [answer] for more information.

Comment: I am unable to find English translation version of that book. I can only locate up to volume 3 in English. Once I fined it I'll add it here.